# Copy a 'change' EventListener function

Tags: javascript, onchange, addeventlistener

I have this HTML tag

```
<input type="file" id="File">
```

which has an event listener

```
document.getElementById("File").addEventListener("change", function() {alert("test")});
```

I would like to copy the function in the listener but all the following lines return null or undefined

```
document.getElementById("File").getAttribute("change")
//null
document.getElementById("File").change
//undefined
document.getElementById("File").getAttribute("onchange")
//null
document.getElementById("File").onchange
//null
```

How can I copy the anonymous function from the listener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

You didn't keep a reference to it, and there is no API to pull it out of the list of listeners.

Refactor your code so you keep a reference to it from the start.

```
function myChangeHandler (event) {
    alert("test");
}
document.getElementById("File").addEventListener("change", myChangeHandler);
```

Comment: alright, that's annoying. I can't really refactor the code because the event listener gets created by a framework

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could trigger the event of the original object with `dispatchEvent()`. But note, if the function uses `this` reference it will refer to the original element the event is attached to. Same is true if the `event` paramter is used (`function(event){}`).

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log("test");
  console.log("triggered element id: " + this.id);
});

document.getElementById("manual").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("test").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

```html
<input id="test">
<button id="manual">manual</button>
```

Another alternative is to overwrite the standard `addEventListener()` function so it will store a reference to the given function. This is an example of this. You probable want to store the reference in a different way but kept it easy as an example.

You only have to make sure that the function is overwritten before the element is created.

```js
//Store the orignal addEventListener() function under a new name so we can still use it.
Node.prototype.originalAddEventListener = Node.prototype.addEventListener;
//Create a variable where we store the handler for the #test1 element
var test1Handler;

//overwrite the orignal function with our own so it will store a reference to the #test1 event handler in the variable
Node.prototype.addEventListener = function(e, fn){
  if(this.id === 'test1') {
    test1Handler = fn;
  }
  this.originalAddEventListener(e, fn);
}

//Attach event with the overwritten function, lets say this is done by an extarnal libary.
document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.log("Changing element id: " + this.id);
});

//When the button is clicked the change handler of test1 is copied to test2.
document.getElementById('exec').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.getElementById('test2').addEventListener('change', test1Handler);
});
```

```html
<label for="test1">Test 1</label><input id="test1"><br>
<button id="exec">Add Test 1 change handler to Test 2</button><br>
<label for="test2">Test 2</label><input id="test2"><br>
```

If you want to do this for the window object you probably need to overwrite `window.addEventListener` because window isn't a `Node`

Comment: great solution, I haven't described my problem completely, I would like to copy the event function to use it elsewhere and then remove the eventlistener. Its probably not possible.

Comment: @MehdiNellen Not sure if and how this would work. But perhaps you could overwrite the standard `addEventListener()` function so it will store a reference to the given function somewhere. Just an out of the box idea. Might be worth to investigate.

Comment: @MehdiNellen Updated my answer with a simple example of my out of the box idea. Hopefully it will help you.